# Comparing two dates which are in different time zone

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to compare two dates (datetime datatype) which are in different time zones in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Do i need to worry about DST when converting PST to EST? Looks like there will always be 3 hour difference.

In the following script, the transaction date is in PST timezone and @Date parameter is in EST time zone;

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2019/03/09 00:01:57.000'

SELECT  
    f.[CustomerNum] ,
    f.[Amount] ,
    f.[TransactionDate] ,
    cus.Linkdate            
FROM    
    [Transaction] f
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Customer cus ON cus.CusNum = f.CustomerNum AND cus.OID = f.OID
WHERE   
    f.TransactionDate > @Date
```

Would this work?

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(TZoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), fpn.TransactionDate)> DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEPART(TZoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()), @Date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The offset between PST and EST is 3 hours.

```
WHERE f.TransactionDate > DATEADD(hour, 3, @Date)
```

Comment: would this take care of DST ?

Comment: What you mean by DST ?

Comment: Daylight saving time (DST)

Comment: Ho I see, I think i can propose another solution for this.

Comment: Ok, after some research, handle the DST with SQL Server 2008 seems to be difficult, some people build a specific function for this.  Unfortunately I can't help you more.

Comment: i am going to try this DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()), @Date)

Comment: Comment again if you found something, i'm curious. It will be easier if you were on SQL Server 2016 ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your parameter is going to be time zone sensitive, it's better that you use a data type that explicitly depicts its time zone, like `datetimeoffset`. Then you can use `switchoffset` to change to the time zone you need.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIMEOFFSET = '2019/03/09 00:01:57.000 -05:00' -- EST
SELECT  
    f.[CustomerNum] ,
    f.[Amount] ,
    f.[TransactionDate] ,
    cus.Linkdate            
FROM    
    [Transaction] f
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Customer cus ON cus.CusNum = f.CustomerNum AND cus.OID = f.OID
WHERE   
    f.TransactionDate > cast(switchoffset(@Date,'-08:00') as datetime) -- PST
```

Comment: do i need to worry about DST when converting PST to EST? Looks like there will always be 3 hour difference.

Comment: That depends on how you input your `transactiondate`.

Comment: Transaction date is going to be in PST time

Comment: @user1263981 Then, yes, it will always be 3 hour difference as long as it stays PST consistently (and not PDT).